# Parsing JSON (C#)

Tags: c#, json

I have the following text response:

```
Game = [1, "MyGame", {
    1: ["Role1", 2], 
    2: ["Role2", 2], 
    3: ["Role3", 3], 
    4: ["Role4", 4] 
    }, { }];
Players = [
    [5, "Player1", 2], 
    [4, "Player2", 21], 
    [9, "Player3", 22], 
    [0, "Player4", 23], 
    [26, "Player5", 24], 
    [1, "Player6", 25], 
    [2, "Player7", 26], 
    [9, "Player8", 27], 
    [1, "Player9", 28], 
    [7, "Player10", 29],
    [5, "Player11", 30], 
    [2, "Player12", 31], 
    [3, "Player13", 32], 
    [7, "Player14", 33], 
    [3, "Player15", 34], 
    [1, "Player16", 35]
];
```

I need parse this context. How can I do it? I am using C#.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! *This site helps solving issues with your code*. When you have results which are different from expected, or when you get an error, then you should **post your code** here and **describe what results you have now and what are your expectations**. After that community will help you to solve issues and (sometimes) it'll give you some guidance. That is how stackoverflow works. Currently your question doesn't have all required information. Please **edit** your question and add code with problem description if you want to get some help.

Comment: Are you looking for a 3rd party JSON-parsing library, or do you want to write your own?

Comment: Note that what you've provided isn't valid JSON.

Comment: It looks like Javascript, not JSON.

Comment: Can I corrected it in order to properly parse?

Answer (score 0):

try to use: System.Web.Helpers
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.json(v=vs.111).aspx

```
dynamic data = Json.Decode(json);
```

Comment: of course, input should be a json not a javascript %)